# What is the difference (if any) between the [JsonRequired] and [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] attributes in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

As mentioned in the title, although I've looked at the documentation for the following attributes, I don't understand what the different use cases would be.

```
[JsonRequired]
public string someProperty;

[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
public string someOtherProperty;
```

Is there a situation when we should use one over the other?

Links researched: [JsonRequiredAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonRequiredAttribute.htm), [JsonPropertyAttribute class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm), [JsonPropertyAttribute required](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm)

Comment: I _think_ they are the same. `JsonRequired` is just a shorthand. On the other hand, you would use `JsonProperty` if you also want to specify other properties of the JSON property, like `PropertyName`, `Order` and `ReferenceLoopHandling`. Don't quote me on that though...

Comment: Seems the same, I test them with serializing and deserializing, they behave the same, throw the same exception.